# Add multiple filters in TEXTAFTER

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to filter out a column in my data set.

I want everything that is after "-", after "/", and if there are two "-" "-" I want whats after the second dash too.

Please help!

Thanks.

I have tried only for the first filter in column E:

=TEXTAFTER(D2:D81, "-")

|  | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Location** | **Manager** |
| **2** | Location 1 - Cassie | Cassie |
| **3** | Location 2/ Anthony/Arrie | Anthony/Arrie |
| **4** | Location 3 - T Mobile - Stacy | Stacy |

[The solution I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJQS1.png)

Comment: Why is T-Mobile excluded from the result in row 4? (Or, why do the first examples only mention a name after the location # and the final example includes more text)

Comment: Please post few more examples its not clear, agreed on what said above ^^^

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
=TEXTAFTER (D2:D81, {"- ", "/ "})
```

Add multiple delimiter within curly braces.  From picture it seems you have a trailing space after each of the delimiter {"- ", "/ "}.

Even this would work

```
=TEXTAFTER(D2:D81, " ", -1)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. But what if I had two - -. For example: T-Mobile-Cassie. How do I extract Cassie?

Comment: Only T-Mobile-Cassie?  No location

Comment: Yes so i want to extra just "Cassie" if the Location column has T - Mobile - Cassie for instance. How to avoid the two - -?

Comment: @jack you sent a question with minimal examples, as picture, not data. You get a response which works for given data. You should accept the answer `=TEXTAFTER(D2:D4,{"/ ","- "},-1)` or improve your question with proper examples. The example in your comments differs from the picture, but that doesn't make Rashed's contribution wrong.